# HTML/Javascript/CSS Desktop Applications

Tags: javascript, html, activex

I have written a program in HTML, Javascript and CSS, and I am displaying it in IE. I'm dependent on IE because data is written to, and read from an Excel File and I need to use ADO for that.
However, the "An activex object is trying to interact with oter parts of the page..." prompt is very irritating, seeing as it is an application that will be store locally on the user's computer, and will not be a web application. I find HTA difficult to debug and it seems as though it hasnt been updated in a while. I can't add my application to trusted sites and use custom level to deal with the activex prompt because it is stored on my computer. I was thinking on storing it on my local host, as I would then be able to add it to trusted site, but this would require adjustments to the user's computer.
     Ao my question is, what is the best way for me to display my html/javascript/css program, as a desktop application, with little or no need to change any settings on the user's computer, that could read/write to and from excel spreadsheets (or if you know a better way of dealing with this data), and is stores on the user's couter rather than as a web application?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated:)

Answer (score 1):

Write a windows application instead and use the Apis of excel. Your model of HTML CSS js will not work well with security.

Comment: I don't have any experience with c# i'm afraid:) What about adobe air?

Comment: I am not sure if adobe air allows you to interact with excel files , I might not be the right person to comment on that